# .OBJ .FBX .MTL Files Won't import Textures

Tags: import

Total noob here. Blender 2.93.6. I downloaded an .obj, .fbx and an .mtl of a ship and when I import either .obj or the .fbx I can’t get the texture to show no matter what advice I’ve read. Find missing files and many other things I tried following to the best of my very limited ability. I’m only using this for still images that I can turn around. The model maker told me “I don't work in Blender, and I don't know how to work with materials and add textures there.I tried to add basic textures in 3ds Max and export them to files, like textures are displayed in blender (fbx file exactly ). “.
If you try to help please explain as if you’re talking to an 8 year old. I’m brand new to this. Thanks.

Comment: The .obj/.mtl will need to have come with image files, did you download any? Open the .mtl in a text editor and paste the first dozen or so lines here.

Comment: # 3ds Max Wavefront OBJ Exporter v0.97b - (c)2007 guruware
# File Created: 26.08.2021 11:48:25

newmtl ship_BP_props
 Ns 10.0000
 Ni 1.5000
 d 1.0000
 Tr 0.0000
 Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
 illum 2
 Ka 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 Kd 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000

Comment: Did you download image files? None of those lines reference an image file. There should be a line with a filename if it has textures.

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for helping. There’s 3 folders of textures that came in a zip file. Base, props, Sail Cloth Metal. 18 jpg files. I’ve tried different combinations of importing them. And the mtl file. Just a grey ship. Jeff.

Comment: The .mtl file needs to have a line with the filename of a texture file. Look for something that ends in .jpg.

Comment: This is part of the mlt file. It’s all like this. No jpg.

# 3ds Max Wavefront OBJ Exporter v0.97b - (c)2007 guruware
# File Created: 26.08.2021 11:48:25

newmtl ship_BP_props
 Ns 10.0000
 Ni 1.5000
 d 1.0000
 Tr 0.0000
 Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
 illum 2
 Ka 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 Kd 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000

Comment: Then the .mtl file doesn't have textures so its not surprising they won't import. You could try setting them up manually after import instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. (o:

Comment: Could you please point me in the direction of what I should research to set the textures up manually?
Like “ You need to go into this pane or window and attach this to that”. A general idea so I know where to look. Thanks. Jeff.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Uc47kxW.jpg

Comment: Thanks. Very nice of you to take the time. I really appreciate it. Jeff